# Chrome Screen Reader Extension Breaking Styles

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm attempting to make my project more accessible and am doing some testing with the [Chrome Screen Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-reader/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn/related?hl=en) extension. Unfortunately, when the screen reader is active, it seems to break all styles in my project's shadow DOM (none are showing at all), and pressing button elements also doesn't seem to function (though I suspect that this is due to the buttons adding/removing classes within the shadowDOM, which doesn't seem to work due to shadowDOM styles not being applied).

Is this the default behavior for this extension? Is there any way I can work around it?

Comment: I can't help on that particular extension. However, I can only strongly encourage you to try a true screen reader used in the real life by real people: NVDA or Jaws under Windows, VoiceOver under Mac and iOS, or Talkback under Android. Your testing will be much more representative. Browser extensions are often far from supporting standards correctly and/or behave quite a lot different from conventional screen readers.

Comment: Preach, what @QuentinC said.